SQL - Display 0 on a count with months where there is no data
I hope someone can help.
I have been attempting to tackle this problem for some time. I have two tables "admissions" and "month data".
The admissions table contains the two fields "admission_date" and "admission_id" - ID id the value that is counted as well as "centre_id" for filtering purposes. What  wish to be able to do is count all the admissions for any given month, for any given centre_id, and display them. If there is a 0 value, just display 0. I need to do this for each year.
So a 2024 query would display all the records for centre = 2 and show the admission_ids counted in each month for 2024 or return a 0 if none exist.
This is the code I have been using.
SELECT MONTHNAME(month) MONTH, COUNT(admission_id) COUNT
FROM rescue_month_data
LEFT JOIN rescue_admissions
ON EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM rescue_month_data.month) = EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM rescue_admissions.admission_date)     
WHERE rescue_admissions.centre_id = 1 AND YEAR(month)=2023 AND rescue_admissions.admission_date IS NULL
GROUP BY MONTH(month)
ORDER BY MONTH(month)

For some reason, unbeknownst to me, the query returns all the months back EXCEPT may and June. These months are present in the month data table AND there are admissions for those months too. There must be a problem somewhere but I'm a novice at this sort of think and not sure how to adapt this query to make it work.
I'm not sure if the query needs to be done at the centre_id level first then do the admissions/date stuff on that data.
I would really appreciate the help if anyone can.
Kind regards & many thanks
Dan
Table: month data
Columns: month_id, month_name (txt), month (date), count (int)

data: 

1, January-23, 01 January 2023, 0
2, February-23, 01 February 2023, 0
3, March-23, 01 March 2023, 0
4, April-23, 01 April 2023, 0
5, May-23, 01 May 2023, 0
6, June-23, 01 June 2023, 0
7, July-23, 01 July 2023, 0
8, August-23, 01 August 2023, 0
9, September-23, 01 September 2023, 0
10, October-23, 01 October 2023, 0
11, November-23, 01 November 2023, 0
12, December-23, 01 December 2023, 0

Table admissions
Columns: admission_id, centre_id, admission_date

Data:
1, 1, May 31 2023 8:49 am
2, 2, May 31 2023 10:49 am
3, 2, June 31 2023 8:49 am
4, 1, June 31, 2023 8:49 am
5, 1, July 31, 2023 8:49 am
6, 1, May 31, 2023 8:49 am
7, 2, August 31, 2023 8:49 am
8, 2, August 31, 2023 11:49 am
9, 2, December 31, 2023 8:49 am
10, 2, December 31, 2023 8:49 am
11, 1, December 31, 2023 8:49 am

(in the actual table the above data continues in the same way for 2024)
Desired output for query centre_id=2 and year 2023 should be:



month
t




January
0


February
0


March
0


April
0


May
1


June
1


July
0


August
2


September
0


October
0


November
0


December
2




please provide example rescue_month_data and rescue_admissions data for April, May, and June

Please provide a Minimal Reproducible example containing a table structure, example data and expected result. And also tag the sql server product you are using

putting filters on rescue_admissions (rescue_admissions.centre_id = 1 ) in your where clause is making your join an inner join.  Move it to the on clause.

SQL Order of Execution

I do not know the SQL product. This ia whats listed under info: 10.6.18-MariaDB-cll-lve-log.
@Andrew - I'll try that but the line is literally under the on clause as it is?

@DanLindley, See MatBailie's answer below.

As per the comments, WHERE clauses are asserted after the OUTER JOIN.
Either put the filtering in the join, or a sub query.
Also...

you should always fully qualify references (specify which table a column is from)
don't use keywords as aliases

SELECT
   MONTHNAME(m.month)      MONTH_NAME,
   COUNT(a.admission_id)   COUNT_ADMISSIONS
FROM
   rescue_month_data   AS m
LEFT JOIN
   rescue_admissions   AS a
      ON EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM m.month) = EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM a.admission_date)     
      AND a.centre_id = 1
      -- AND a.admission_date IS NULL
      -- this has been removed as it makes no sense to me
WHERE
   YEAR(m.month)=2023
GROUP BY
   MONTH(m.month)
ORDER BY
   MONTH(m.month)

Or...
SELECT
   MONTHNAME(m.month)      MONTH_NAME,
   COUNT(a.admission_id)   COUNT_ADMISSIONS
FROM
   rescue_month_data   AS m
LEFT JOIN
(
   SELECT
      *
   FROM
      rescue_admissions
   WHERE
      centre_id = 1
      -- AND admission_date IS NULL
      -- this has been removed as it makes no sense to me 
)
   AS a
      ON EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM m.month) = EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM a.admission_date)
WHERE
   YEAR(m.month)=2023   
GROUP BY
   MONTH(m.month)
ORDER BY
   MONTH(m.month)


Both examples worked perfectly thank you
I'm very new to all this and still learning. I will take on board the points you have addressed for next time I write a SQL query.  Thanks again.

Do you know how I could expand this to add an additional table into the query?
I have a further table network_cons which is the centre_id and a network_id.
I'd like to join this table in, count the same data but this time for all the centres part of the same network.  I had a play around and tried to join inside the sub query but i dont think i was getting  right
network_cons data is centre_id and network_id so 1, 1 | 2, 1 | 3, 1, | 1, 2, | 3, 2 and so on

@DanLindley Please open a new question with a [mre]
